# FilesProcessor and viewhelper f:uri.image

Tags: typo3

I added to a Fluidtemplate cObject a FilesProcessor:

```
dataProcessing {
  10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
  10.references.fieldName = media
}
```

in my fluid template i get the correct files object:

```
0 => TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReferenceprototypeobject
1 => TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReferenceprototypeobject
```

This works:

```
<f:for each="{files}" as="file" iteration="i">
    <img src="{f:uri.image(image: file, width: '967c', height: '967c')}" alt="">
</f:for>
```

but this throws an exception:

```
<img src="{f:uri.image(image: files.0, width: '967c', height: '967c')}" alt="">
```

Does anyone know why? When i debug it with d:debug i get for file the foreach exact the same output like files.0 without foreach.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the key when debugging `{files}`?

Comment: <f:debug>{files}</debug> 
    0 => TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReferenceprototypeobject
    1 => TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReferenceprototypeobject

Comment: I presume using the for loop i get an object and using files.0 i get an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your inline notation not working because of you pass `null` value in notation. because of `files.0` output is `null`

You store image as object. so you can't get this fields value like `files.o` see below screenshot.
[image]